# How to bind a local component's data object to an external component

Tags: vue.js, vue-trix

how do you use a local component's data attriutes to bind an external component's `v-model`

for example i have this component

```
<publish-blog>
<VueTrix v-model="form.editorContent">
</publish-blog>
```

so the `form.editorContent` there refers to the `publish-blog` component's form.editorContent inside data, how do I do that ?

Comment: You can consider using Vuex (https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for sharing data across components instead, AFAIK it tends to get very ugly without some sort of store pattern.

Comment: I don't want to use vuex. for this one

Comment: A quick and dirty way of doing this would be to store the data you need in the global `window` object. Having said that, I would still highly recommend using Vuex instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a prop to the `publish-blog` component.

This would be what ever page or component you are using the publish blog on, though to be honest I'm not sure why you would not just put the `VueTrix` component inside of the `publish-blog` component.

This would be on what ever page/component you are wanting it on.

```
<template>
    <PublishBlog :trix="trix">
        <VueTrix v-model="trix" />
    </PublishBlog>
</template>

<script>
import PublishBlog from './PublishBlog.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        PublishBlog,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            trix: '',
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

and inside of the publish blog component make the `form.editorContent` the prop passed or a default value.

But without a global store/state you are stuck with props.

UPDATE: Showing what a publish blog component might look like

PublishBlog.vue

```
<template>
    <section>
        what ever goes here.
        <slot />
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'PublishBlog',
    props: {
        trix: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                editorContent: this.trix
            },
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Just the string trix? that will be passed?

Comment: That is fine. it still works the same way, and na see how the prop has `:` before it? that is binding the prop to the data variable `trix` so what ever that variable is equal to is what will be passed. So when VueTrix updates the `v-model` variable trix to its content. the prop will also be updated.

Comment: I have updated my response to show what the publish blog component might look like, you said you are doing it inline so it may look different.